# Updating MySQL 5.6 query to MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, upgrade

The below same query is returning different results for MySQL 5.6 and MySQL 5.7

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.NAME
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.S_ID
JOIN T3 ON T2.R_ID = T3.DR_ID
WHERE
T2.START_DATE <= '2022-10-01'
T2.END_DATE > '2023-10-01'
AND T3.DT_ID = 2
ORDER BY T1.ID
```

I expect the above query to return same results in MySQL 5.6 and MySQL 5.7 databases which have the same data.
Unfortunately, MySQL 5.7 is returning more records which is wrong, but if I remove `ORDER BY T1.ID` for MySQL 5.7 it has the same results as what I get using MySQL 5.6 (with `ORDER BY`) and the result is correct.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I am not sure how `order by` can change the number of rows.  Please post the table schema, sample data, sample output, and the exact versions of the two queries, with and without order by.

Comment: Order by will not change the number of rows returned. Something else is causing this.